# Mysql Workbench 6.2 CE Invalid date format

Tags: mysql-workbench, database-schema

What is the correct data type for dates that Mysql Workbench 6.2 CE would accept this date and time format 1/1/2012 0:17 ?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL Workbench doesn't care about the format. For the tool it's just a string. The question is: what does the server expect? You can find many examples on this page: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html.

Also this question gives a good suggestion (DATE_FORMAT), which would at least give you options for different display. When inserting dates however you have to conform to the used ISO date format.